# react native reanimated onscroll event doesn't fire

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use react-native-reanimated (v2) in expo (sdk 48), the `onScroll` event doesn't work neither in `FlatList` nor in `ScrollView`, yes I have added `'react-native-reanimated/plugin'` in `babel.config.js` in plugins array as last item.

package.json:

```
"expo": "~48.0.18",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4"
```

babel.config.js

```
plugins: ['expo-router/babel', 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
```

code:

```
import Animated,{useSharedValue,useAnimatedScrollHandler} from 'react-native-reanimated'

const Home = () => {
  const scrollOffset = useSharedValue(0)
  const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler({
        onScroll: (event) => {
            console.log("event", event); // NO LOGS IN TERMINAL
            scrollOffset.value = event.contentOffset.y;
        },
    });
  console.log(scrollOffset.value) // always 0 even on scrolling
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Header />
      <Animated.FlatList
        data={products}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({item}) => <View>...</View>}
        onScroll={scrollHandler}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

I followed the docs and did everything according to it but still the `onScroll` event just doesn't fire anymore.

Here is a reproducible snack example: https://snack.expo.dev/@rog9274/rn-reanimated-scroll